# Banno PluginCard URL and its Redirection

Tags: node.js

Is it possible for Banno to route the traffic internally via jConnect to a server on our network? So we dont have to expose the end point to the public?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from Tier2 analyst:

No. The purpose of them is that are exposed to the internet and users can't directly hit jconnect.
users can't directly hit jconnect